# Navigation on OpenStreetMap

Tags: navigation, gps, openstreetmap

What is the best way to get a route or directions from OpenStreetMaps?

I've found [YourNavigation.org](http://www.yournavigation.org/), but there are wrote that this is YOURS showcase.
Is there a way to use some online service instead of self-deploying of the YOURS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use YOURS as the routing engine in your application
>
> The routing API is OpenSource and open to 3rd party applications. This means that you can either implement a copy of the routing API or *use this website* as the routing backend for your application. See the [wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS%20wiki) link below for more information.

From their About page (Emphasize mine).

Why can you not use their website for the routing? The Wiki says "fair-use", so unless you produce way too much traffic it should be fine. The admin will try to contact you if you cause too much load on the server and will try to resolve this. Until then you are fine, and I guess that would probably be the time when  you should consider self-deploying or paying for the service. It's not likely that you'll get high-traffic for free anywhere, I suppose.

Comment: @skayred, showcase seems just to mean that it is too show the software as a demo. I would use it but maybe be aware that it could become unavailable. If you sent the owner a mail to warn you when he is taking the server down, he might be willing to do this.

Comment: Where does this service get routing data?

Comment: @Alexey, I don't know. Can you find out for yourself and post the result here as a comment or link?

Answer (score 0):

There are other API's available for routing, that can be used by your application instead of deploying on YOURS.  For example have a look at the Cloudmade API's specifically navi-studio:
http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/navi-studio
This may be better suited for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing for a list of applications and libraries which calculate routes from OpenStreetMap data. (Disclaimer: I am the author of one of them.)